# Unable to start VM after mounting and adding data to disk

Tags: hyper-v, vhdx

Yesterday I created a VM and configured most things I needed. At some point I accidentally clicked on checkpoint instead of start (who placed those buttons so close to each other).

I continued working and stopped the machine when I was finished.

Today I had to place some data (program installs) and just mounted the vhdx and added the data (it's a dynamically expanding disk). I unmounted the disk and tried to start the VM.

The VM doesn't start giving this error:

[image]

I read about how to fix it [here](https://fleexlab.blogspot.com/2016/09/when-hyper-v-machines-fail-to-start.html), but that didn't work.

Trying to change the disk gives me this error:

[image]

How can I fix this, so the machine can start?

Or maybe at least give me a hint where I can see the progress of the disk merge and possibly cancel it?

---

Update:

I removed the checkpoint settings and then removed the hard drive. Now the machine started, but I lost all settings. Since this is just a testing VM, no real data is lost.

I will continue to do my settings as I didn't really loose any data, but I would not risk this on a production server.

Comment: @dsstorefile1: I'm not really an administrator, so I don't know what you're saying, could you elaborate

Comment: @dsstorefile1: yes that's correct, but how can I resolve this? In the future I know what not to do, but when it's done, how can it be fixed?